# Does this reduce down to the PolyGamma function?

Tags: limits, hypergeometric-function, polygamma

Does this reduce down to the [PolyGamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) function?

$H_n=$
$$\lim_{s\to 0} \, \left(-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{s}+1\right)^n (s+1)^{-n} \left(\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{s}\right)^k \left(\prod _{i=0}^{k-1} (i+n)\right) \left(\prod _{i=0}^{k-1} (i+n)\right)}{k! \left(\prod _{i=0}^{k-1} (i+n+1)\right)}\right)}{n}+\frac{(s+1)^{-n}}{n}+s-\log (s)\right)$$

Mathematica tells me it reduces down to:

$$\frac{1}{n}+\psi ^{(0)}(n)+\gamma$$

but I don't know where to start to make that happen.

Comment: The series inside is a Gauss hypergeometric function of $-1/s$. Therefore you need the asymptotics of this function at $-\infty$ which can be obtained using connection formulas relating $_2F_1(-1/s)$ with $_2F_1(s)$. This will presumably produce $s^n\ln s$ and polygamma.